# webpack hide stack trace from babel errors

Tags: webpack, babeljs, javascript-build

I have a relatively standard webpack setup: webpack + babel-stage-0

If there's a syntax error, babel gives me a very helpful error message but there's also a stack trace completely irrelevant to my code, which is often longer than the terminal itself.

[image]

Is there a way to hide the stacktrace from `Parser.pp.raise`

I know this is a very minor thing, but having the stack trace hidden will mean less visual noise, and I dont have to scroll up half a terminal window to see my error message.

#### Things I've tried

I tried hiding stderr with:

```
webpack --watch > /dev/null
```

but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same problem and there are apparently no real solutions to this. So I came up with a hack:

`$ webpack --watch --color | grep -v '^    at .*/node_modules/'`

This will filter webpack output to remove traceback for the node_modules dir, and the `--color` option ensures that grep doesn't remove your colors

Comment: Apparently grep has a non-zero exit code when there are no matches. If you want to use this in a NPM script, use `npx webpack --color | grep -v '^    at ' || true` (with whatever other arguments you need of course, just note the `|| true`).

Answer (score 0):

If you're [running webpack via the API](https://webpack.github.io/docs/node.js-api.html) (e.g. from a gulpfile) you can filter the exception messages with this one-liner:

```
// filter webpack/babel error traces
const filterStackTraces = err =>
  err.toString().split(/[\r\n]+/).filter(line => ! line.match(/^\s+at Parser/)).join(os.EOL);

// example use:
compiler.run( (err, stats) => {
  if (err) return done( new gutil.PluginError('webpack', err));
  if ( stats.hasErrors() ) {
    const statDetails = stats.toJson({errorDetails: false});
    // print out parse errors
    statDetails.errors.forEach((e) => gutil.log(error(tag), filterStackTraces(e)));
    return done(new gutil.PluginError('webpack', 'Parse/ build error(s)'));
  }
  gutil.log(gutil.colors.green(tag), stats.toString({colors: true}));
  done();
});
```

It will remove the stack traces while not touching the error message and source context snippet and leaves colors intact.