# How to minimize babel-parser error stack trace?

Tags: typescript, webpack, babel-loader, babel-parser

Is it not possible at all to minimze the error stack trace from the babel-loader in webpack? Take this as an example: Everything after line 67, I'm really not interested in seeing, how to get rid of it, I've been searching for ways to make it less verbose, and the closest I've gotten is to modify the stats object in webpack.config, but not enough to minimize the error stack trace... :(

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/pages/collection/index.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /User/MyUser/resources/js/pages/collection/index.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (64:6)

  62 |       products: temp.querySelector('[data-products]').innerHTML,
  63 |       pagination: temp.querySelector('[data-pagination]').innerHTML
> 64 |       ctas: temp.querySelector('[data-ctas]').innerHTML,
     |       ^
  65 |     };
  66 |   };
  67 |
    at instantiate (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:653:32)
    at constructor (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:947:12)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.raise (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3271:19)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.unexpected (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3301:16)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.expect (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3643:28)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseObjectLike (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11647:14)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseExprAtom (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11167:23)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseExprSubscripts (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10880:23)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseUpdate (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10863:21)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseMaybeUnary (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10839:23)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseMaybeUnary (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9758:20)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10677:61)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseExprOps (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10682:23)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseMaybeConditional (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10659:23)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseMaybeAssign (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10620:21)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseMaybeAssign (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9702:20)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseExpressionBase (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10574:23)
    at /User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10570:39
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.allowInAnd (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12260:16)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseExpression (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10570:17)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseReturnStatement (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12943:28)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseStatementContent (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12590:21)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseStatementContent (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9399:18)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseStatementLike (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12557:17)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseStatementListItem (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12537:17)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13129:61)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseBlockBody (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13122:10)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseBlock (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13110:10)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseFunctionBody (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11932:24)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseArrowExpression (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11907:10)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseAsyncArrowFromCallExpression (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11084:10)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseAsyncArrowFromCallExpression (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9682:18)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseCoverCallAndAsyncArrowHead (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10995:27)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseSubscript (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10922:19)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseSubscript (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9240:18)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseSubscripts (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10893:19)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseExprSubscripts (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10884:17)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseUpdate (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10863:21)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseMaybeUnary (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10839:23)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseMaybeUnary (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9758:20)
    at TypeScriptParserMixin.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/User/MyUser/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10677:61)
```

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34828222/450127, which unfortunately doesn't have a good answer.